# Write a variable into a buffer

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am very new to node.js and I think I understand the basics of how it functions but I feel like I am not seeing something that is vital to how fs.write and buffers function.

I am trying to send a user defined variable over socket.io and write it into an html file.  I have a main site that has the button, when clicked it sends the information to the socket in a variable.

The thing I can't figure out is how to insert the variable into the html file.

I can save strings that I type, into a file:
(e.g.) `var writeBuffer = new Buffer ('13');`

But not variables that I put in:
(e.g.) `var writeBuffer = new Buffer ($(newval));`

I even tried different encoding methods, I think I am missing something.

**Server.js**

```js
var newval = "User String";
var fd = fsC.open(fileName, 'rs+', function (error, fd) {
  if (error) { throw error }
  var writeBuffer = new Buffer($(newval));
  var bufferLength = writeBuffer.length;
  fsC.write( fd, writeBuffer, 0, bufferLength, 937,
    function (error, written) {
      if (error) { throw error }
      fsC.close(fd, function() {
        console.log('File Closed');
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap `newval` in `$()`. `new Buffer(newval)` should be all that's needed.

Comment: I've tried that too, with $(newval) it writes junk characters
and with (newval) is writes a blank space.

Comment: Are you trying to insert an arbitrary string into the 937th character of an HTML file and then serve that HTML file back?

Comment: Also, what is $ supposed to be in the context of node.js? It seems almost like you're trying to wrap a string with jQuery as if it were a css selector.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do.
I am using jsdom with nodejs so the jQuery commands are possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of jsdom 4.0.0 or later, it will not work with Node.js. As per the [jsdom github readme](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#install):

> Note that as of our 4.0.0 release, jsdom no longer works with
>   Node.js™, and instead requires io.js. You are still welcome to install
>   a release in the 3.x series if you use Node.js™.

Comment: I am using version 3 for that exact reason